# Cocos2d, How to make a score timer

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I am still new to cocos2d and was wondering if any of you guys can help me make a score timer.  I seen some questions like this but looks like it is for a way older version of cocos2d. I want the timer to start at zero and go up in mins and seconds. Really appreciate any help or advice I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a NSTimer that runs every second and calls a method that updates the timer.

Define an integer called seconds and another called minutes in the header.

```
-(void)updateTheTime {

    seconds++;

    if (seconds == 60) {

        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

    }

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", minutes, seconds];

}
```